# How to Disable the ChildNode(s) of a TreeView in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, c#-4.0

I have created a Treeview using HierarchicalDataTemplate :

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate" >
                <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
            </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildTopics}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <sdk:TreeView Width="400"  Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}" x:Name="myTreeView">
```

Now If I want to disable the tree view , then have to just :

```
myTreeView.IsEnabled = false;
```

But , I just want to disable few nodes.

Silverlight doesn't support data Triggers and there is no way I am able to access the child nodes.

So How do I disable the Child Nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, since you want to disable some specific items, why don't give the VM a property to do so? E.g.

```
public ItemVm : ViewModelBase //assuming you're are using such a class
{
    public string Title
    {
        get { return GetValue(() => Title); }
        set { SetValueAndNotify(() => Title, value); }
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return GetValue(() => IsEnabled); }
        set { SetValueAndNotify(() => IsEnabled, value); }
    }
}
```

Now you could modify your `Template` like

```xml
<sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildTopics}" 
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}">
     <Border IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" BorderThickness="0" Background={x:Null} >
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"  FontWeight="Bold" />
     </Border>
</sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Hope this helps. Please note, it's not tested.